# skrollr transform from bottom left

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm using skrollr to animate the scale of some svg elements.  The problem is I'd like to animate them expanding from a bottom left position, but instead they are animating from the top left (default art board anchor point).

```
...
<g  data-0="transform:scale(0)" 
    data-600="transform:scale(1)">
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvNGE/

You can see it above.  Is there a tag I can add to the svg that will change its anchor point, something I can do in skrollr or a way of exporting it from illustrator that will do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure skrollr is meant to be used on SVG elements, it works on webkit but I'm unsure it will work on other browsers (just a heads up).

---

You need to specify the transform origin, `-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;`

```
<g data-0="transform:scale(0)" data-600="transform:scale(1)" class="bottom-left skrollable skrollable-between" style="-webkit-transform: scale(0.19333333333333333); -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swwRB/

Comment: skrollr does support SVG. **But** SVG doesn't have a `transform` style (see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties). It only has a transform _attribute_, which skrollr does not animate (see https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/204).